# Mosaic of images using CSS

Tags: html, image, css

I'm trying to figure it out how to achieve this but it's giving me nightmares. I want to show a mosaic of images, 3 per row for desktop resolution. Same height but different width, and to maintain image ratio when resizing. The problem is that when changing the width for the 3 images (different widths for each one) it doesn't do anything. I"ll appreciate your help on this. I have this code inside my container:

```css
.responsive {
padding: 0 6px;
float: left;
width: 33.3333333%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.img img {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive">   
<div class="img"> <a href="#">
<img src="images/work/thumbnail1.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400"></a>     
</div>
```

```
<div class="responsive">   
<div class="img"> <a href="#">
<img src="images/work/thumbnail1.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="400"></a>     
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.responsive {
padding: 0 6px;
float: left;
width: 33.3333333%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

div.img img {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Is the `.responsive` `width` what isn't working? How's the parent on that element? Did you forget to copy it's `</div>` from your code or it's missing? Also, you should close `<img>`. (ex: `<img src="stuff" />`)

Comment: The CSS might be your prolem. You set the responsive width fixed, but you need it to be different. You can set it to `max-width: 33.333333%` and the div.img img width to auto. Also, try using flexbox to achieve this effect.